# How to capturate escape caracters from of text file in R

Tags: r

I need capture escape character(`\n`) from a text file to save them in a vector.

I am using `scan()`, but I'm not successful with this.

With the field `allowscapes = FALSE`, I get the same result.

My code :

```
myvectorOfWords<-scan("compresion.txt", what="character",sep=" ",allowEscapes = "TRUE")
```

Read 13 items

```
myvectorOfWords
 [1] "hola"       "mundo"      "azul"       ""           "?"          ""           "mundo"     
 [8] "azul"       "marino"     "hola"       "marino"     "seguimos"   "trabajando"
```

The text file "compresion.txt" is this :

```
hola mundo azul  ? 
mundo azul marino hola marino
seguimos trabajando
```

Comment: Use `readChar`: `readChar("compresion.txt",file.info("compresion.txt")$size, useBytes=TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks i will try it.

Comment: Perfect solution!! thank  you very much

Comment: But i  how save the \n character in vector with the more words(one word one position in vector ,one "\n" character other position in vector)? ej:>[1]hola mundo azul  "" ? "" \n [8]mundo azul marino hola marino \n [13]seguimos trabajando \n\n

Comment: If `x` is the result of the line I gave before, try `strsplit(x," |(?<=\n)|(?=\n)",perl=TRUE)[[1]]`. Not sure if I totally got it though.